# Edit data after FILTER in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, filter, edit

I have FILTER some range like "=FILTER(E1:M11;E1:M1=B1)" but I use FILTER for simple access to the cell-data, that must be edit, trying to wright something in to FILTER celLs given an a formula FILTER error...

Comment: Please be more specific what the problem is. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which will help others to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

google sheets does not support editing cells where the output of the formulas rolls out. this is a feature by design, not a bug. if you wish to re-write a print from a formula that formula needs to be inserted with a script, not as an in-cell function

Comment: Even with script, that's impossible. A cell cannot contain both output of formula as well as a user entered value. That's the basic law of any spreadsheet, not just Google sheets.