# How to update filtered data?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Hello I have a problem because I filter my database and then use a map function to get only my firs column. I use and indexOf to get the position of my name but when I try to update some row on my filtered range doesn't work. The code works but find the first coincidence and apply it there. I know it can be because im getting the rang eon my database but I don't know how to apply it only on my filtered data.

This is my code:

When I run the filter function I get the row that I want to edit, but then I don't know how to edit it (I just want to edit the column 5 of that row)

```
function myFilterdata() {

  var basededatos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var baseSht = basededatos.getSheetByName("BASE DE DATOS");
  var dRng = baseSht.getRange(2,1, baseSht.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
  var Criteria1 = baseSht.getRange("G1").getValue();
  var Criteria2 = baseSht.getRange("F1").getValue();
  var Criteria3 = baseSht.getRange ("H1").getValue();
  var nombre = baseSht.getRange("H1").getValue();
  var estatus=baseSht.getRange("J1").getValue();

  var fData = dRng.filter(function(e){return e[0]== Criteria3 && e[1]== Criteria1 && e[2]== Criteria2});
  Logger.log(fData);
  var listanombres=fData.map(filas=>filas[0]);
  Logger.log(listanombres);
  var indice=listanombres.indexOf(nombre)+1;
  Logger.log(indice);

  if(indice==-1){

  }else{
  baseSht.getRange(indice+1,5).setValue(estatus)

  }

  
}
```

Comment: Related question: [Edit data after FILTER in Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73778382/1330560). As both @player0 and TheMaster point out, one cannot edit the result of a filter - whether by formula or script. The solution in your case would be to use a sheet (or part thereof) where you can save the filtered data, edit it as required and copy/paste the edited data back to the relevant line of database. That is, update the data in the database.

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirements. Are you trying to update all cells in filtered rows which match a certain criteria, but your code is only updating the first cell which matches that criteria? If so, are the contents of the cells you want to update plain text, or formula results?

Comment: It is plain text. I basically need to filter an edit like if I did it manually on a table with google sheets.